# How can I use text from a cell as part of a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I do not want to concatenate a string or show the value like `"Some Text " & C12`. I need to use the text in a cell as part of the formula in another cell. For Example:

I have a cell containing a date `17.02.2014`. I need to use that date in a formula within another cell:

```
='17.02.2014'!$AV$6
```

However this date needs to be pulled dynamically, for this example from `E26`. I would have expected it to look something like:

```
='&E26&'!$AV$6
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 10):

Please try:

```
 =indirect(E26&"!"&$AV$6)
```

Indirect is able to read a string as a cell reference. Within the parentheses three elements are concatenated: the content of `E26` (which could be as here a sheet named `17.02.2014`), the required `"!"` and the  content of `AV6` (anchored with `$`s so it does not change if the formula is copied around).

Comment: Tried this and got the error "Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is '03-22-21!'. It is not a valid cell/range reference." How  do you get the close quote before bang?

Comment: Same problem as @motorbaby in comments.  Fixed by quoting the cell reference like this `=indirect(E26&"!"&"$AV$6")`

Answer (score 2):

I just landed here with this issue and the solution was still giving errors. Example:

```
  A                B                      C
1| String        | INDIRECT()             | Result 
-+---------------+------------------------+-------------
2| fred          | =INDIRECT(A2)&"rick"   | #REF
3| fred          | =INDIRECT("A2")&"rick" | fredrick
```

So the instructions "must be and actual string" meant for me that the string is the string "A2" that represents the cell.

I hope it helps the next bloke or darling that comes upon this need.

Unfortunate thing about this is it don't scrape down, auto magically update the cells. So it's a pest.

**Update: This works with dragging down on many cells**

```
    A             B                        C
1| String  | INDIRECT()               | Result 
-+---------+--------------------------+-------------
2|non      | =INDIRECT("A2:A")&"stop" |nonstop
3|short    | =INDIRECT("A2:A")&"stop" |shortstop
4|pit      | =INDIRECT("A2:A")&"stop" |pitstop
5|door     | =INDIRECT("A2:A")&"stop" |doorstop
6|back     | =INDIRECT("A2:A")&"stop" |backstop
```

Comment: Now I want to know why you're building a list of words that end in "stop." :)

Answer (score 0):

The `INDIRECT` function will only accept a range, as explained in the Drive Help:
[image]

The thing with functions like `NOW()` and `TODAY()` is, that they do just that !!

The way to go is by referencing indirectly, like shown in the screenshot (`C5` vs. `C2`).

### Screenshot

[image]

### Reference

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093377

Comment: That file link is dead now

Answer (score 0):

Sorry so late. But I got this to work for me in a similar matter:

```
=INDIRECT(INDIRECT("B13")&"!C2")
```

"translating" to your needs, I think

```
=INDIRECT(INDIRECT("E26")&"!$AV$6")
```

would do the trick!

Comment: This worked for me after adding an additional column containing `=TO_TEXT(B12)` so that the formula would read a date format as a text string. But it only worked for one row. How can I get the formula of the inner INDIRECT to read it as cell so it can be copied?

Comment: Figured it out: Took out the inner INDIRECT.  So, have 3 columns: 1 with the date, 2nd with `=TO_TEXT(B12)` to translate the date into a string, and 3rd column gathering the data into one cell as `=INDIRECT(B13&"!$B$7")` . Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, none of the solutions worked for me to consolidate Google Add-on Timesheet data from multiple sheets onto one sheet Then I tried this...

```
      A                B                      C
1| name of sheet | convert date to text  | value from sheet
-+---------------+-----------------------+------------------
2|     03-15-21  | =TO_TEXT($A2)         | =INDIRECT($B2&"!$B$7")
3|     03-22-21  | =TO_TEXT($A3)         | =INDIRECT($B3&"!$B$7")
```

Had to convert the date to text first. (Those using the Timesheet add-on, note that the value in column C points to the same cell on every sheet; the first cell containing combined time data is B7.)

Column C's formula gives null instead of `!REF` if the sheet is not yet renamed as the date or the sheet does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

##### Question Distilled:

What is the correct syntax to dynamically use the value of a cell (containing a **date**) as the sheet name in a formula.

##### Conditions:

1. Cell values are dates (***C1***)
2. Formula is dynamic (***C2***)
3. Formula includes a non-dynamic static text string`$AV$6` (***C3***) *****

<sup>***** *This assumption is based on the reference that the OP seeks to build:* `'17.02.2014'!$AV$6`</sup>

##### Remarks:

- Questionner refers to 2 cells: `E26` in the active sheet (date) and `17.02.2014!$AV$6` is the cell they are ultimately trying to reference;
- I have used a sheet named `17.02.2014` and also kept the same cell `$AV$6` on that sheet;
- I have changed `E26` (`E26:E?`) to `D2` (`D2:D10`) (largely irrelevant);
- The value I have placed in `17.02.2014!$AV$6` is `"17.02.2014!$AV$6"`.  In other words, a successful reference would return that value.  It is an arbitrary decision that I preferred to a string like `Success` or `I am the destination cell` etc.  Just noting in case the clever among you wonder why `INDIRECT("17.02.2014!$AV$6") = 17.02.2014!$AV$6`
  [image]

##### INDIRECT

[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) is the right function for this question.  The [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) function returns a cell reference specified by a string.

```
Syntax:  =INDIRECT(cell_reference_as_string, [is_A1_notation])

Samples: =INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&B10)

         =INDIRECT("A2")

         =INDIRECT("R2C3", FALSE)
```

##### INDIRECT & Dates

All other things being equal, the [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) formula for this question would be `=INDIRECT(E26&"!$AV$6")`, but that will **not work** with dates in addition to strings that look like dates depending on the locale.

**INDIRECT's problem with dates**
[image]

##### Why is there a problem:

Sheets stores dates as **numbers** representing the number of days that have elapsed since December 31, 1899.  The date `17.02.2014` is stored as `41,687` and `17.02.2014 12:00 PM` is stored as `41,687.5` (1/2 a day = 12 hours).

```
Where 'E26' is the date '17.02.2014',

  =INDIRECT(E26&"!$AV$6") 
  =41687!$AV$6
  =#REF!  //  It is not a valid cell/range reference.
```

A formula should address the original conditions and extending the formula to address some closely related use cases can make the formula less prone to failure.

##### Extended Conditions:

1. Cell values are dates (***C1***)
2. Formula is dynamic (***C2***)
3. Formula includes a non-dynamic static text string `$AV$6` (***C3***)
4. Cell values ***might*** also be strings that *appear* to be dates (***C4***)
5. Date formats might not exactly match tab naming format (***C5***)

##### Basic Formula:

```
 =INDIRECT(TEXT(D2, "dd.mm.yyyy")&"!$AV$6")

+-----------------------------------------+
| To return an arbitrary value if formula |
| errors out, you can wrap it in IFERROR  |
+-----------------------------------------+

 =IFERROR(
    INDIRECT(TEXT(D2, "dd.mm.yyyy")&"!$AV$6"),
    "✗"
 )
```

##### Formula Notes:

1. **Sheet Naming Format**
   This drives the [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) format you choose.  If your sheets are named `yy-mm-dd` then you use `TEXT(D2, "yy-mm-dd")`. In this case the desired format was `TEXT(D2, "dd.mm.yyyy")`
2. **Specific Date Format**
   Using a [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) format that matches the sheet name `TEXT(D2, "dd.mm.yyyy")` instead of simply using [TO_TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285) eliminates another potential error path where a date is correct (underlying number) but the visual representation (date format) is different.   For example, the dates  `17.2.2014` and `17.02.2014` are identical (`41,687` and `41,687`) but the strings `"17.2.2014"` and `"17.02.2014"` are not equivalent.  This approach means the formula will work for **all dates** regardless of their format.
3. **Text Strings**
   It is sometimes difficult to visually differentiate dates, and strings that look like dates.  To make things even more confusing,  Sheets will often coerce a string to a date when the string is similar to the default date format (locale settings):

   - `ISNUMBER(date_string)` will always return **FALSE**;
   - `ISDATE(date_string)` will return **TRUE** if `date_string` is similar to default date formats;
   - `date_string ÷ 1` will return a **number** where `ISDATE(date_string) = TRUE` & `ISNUMBER(date_string) = FALSE`
4. **Error Handling**
   The [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) function in the formula allows a way to deal with strings that are not similar to the default date format.  For example, if some dates are stored as text using one locale, then accessed using a different locale, the strings might just need a simple switch:

```
             string: "2.17.2014"
default date format: 'dd.mm.yyyy'

# Basic Formula (basic error text)

=IFERROR(
   INDIRECT(TEXT(string, "dd.mm.yyyy")&"!$AV$6"),
   "✗")
=✗


# Formula (advanced--but not exhaustive--error handling)

=IFERROR(
   INDIRECT(TEXT(string, "dd.mm.yyyy")&"!$AV$6"),
   INDIRECT(TEXT((LAMBDA(dt, 
      DATE(INDEX(dt,,3),
           INDEX(dt,,IF(INDEX(dt,,1)>12,2,1)),
           INDEX(dt,,IF(INDEX(dt,,1)>12,1,2))))
      (SPLIT(string,REGEXEXTRACT(string,"[^\d]")))),"dd.mm.yyyy")&"!$AV$6"))

=Cell Reference: '02.17.2014!$AV$6'
```

##### Testing Screens:

The screenshots below show a series of tests of various formulas against a list of **dates** and **strings**.

| Heading | Options | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Format** | "Text" or "Date" | Is the value stored as a `string` or a `date` |
| **Like Default** | [image] | Is the format of the `string` or `date` similar to the default format for the locale |
| **÷1** | [image] | Can the value be divided by 1 (i.e. is a `date` or a `string` that can be coerced to a `date`) |
| **ISNUM** | [image] | [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296) function tests if the value is a `number` (date) or `string` |
| **ISDATE** | [image] | [ISDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381) function tests if the value is a `date` or a `string` that can be coerced to a `date` |
| **Reference** | `17.02.2014!$AV$6` **<sub><sup>or</sup></sub>** [image] | Formula success returns `17.02.2014!$AV$6` and failure returns [image] |

**Basic Formula**
[image]

**Formula with advanced error handling**
[image]

##### Older Answers to the [Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57110/)

**<sub>Answer from [2021-03](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153075/)</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>Answer from [2020-12](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149356/)</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>Top-rated answer from [2014-02](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57112/)</sub>**
[image]

- [Answer 2017-02](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/102800):  Not an answer to the question.
- [Answer 2017-12](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112532):  Not an answer to the question.
- [Answer 2014-02](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57621/): A bit better than "not an answer" (has resources)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue that *motorbaby* was having, the suggested formula worked for just one row at a time, it wouldn't allow me to copy and paste to other rows, E26 remained even though I did not anchor it with "$". I tried the fix using the suggestion he made, but it didnt work for me. But this did:

=INDIRECT((E26)&"!$AV$6")

Comment: If you are going to reference answers and comments you need to include the links.   The issue Motorbaby [referred to](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57110/how-can-i-use-text-from-a-cell-as-part-of-a-formula/169276#comment139579_149356) was tied to quoting `="B3"` will not update when offset however `=B3` will.   `(E26)` and `E26` are not interpreted differently therefore the inclusion of brackets `()` has no bearing.

Answer (score -3):

Code example for single cell (B1 containing a number):

```
="Quick numbers from "&indirect("B1")&" projects"
```